# Regex Problem in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to utilize the following Regex pattern:

```
$regex = '/Name: [a-zA-Z ]*] [0-9]/';
```

When testing it in Rubular, it works fine, but when using PHP the expression never returns true, even when it should. Incidentally, if I remove the "[0-9]" part, it works fine. Is there some difference in PHP's regex syntax that I'm overlooking?

Edit: 
I'm looking for the characters "Name:" then a name containing any number of letters or spaces, then a "]", then a space, then a single number. So
"Name: Chris] 5" would return true and
"Name: Chris] [lorem ipsum]" should return false.

I also tried escaping the second bracket "`\[`" but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: You didn't say what you're trying to match. Also, the second `]` is literal on PHP and Ruby, so you match something like `Name:_Hello World]_4` (underscores for mandatory spaces, just so we can see them)

Comment: first , what are you trying to achive ?

Comment: give example strings you want to match and to which regex should return true.

Comment: Try http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php for PHP regex testing

Comment: Might need to escape the second `]`. As in `'/Name: [a-zA-Z ]*\\] [0-9]/'`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear without examples what your use case, but it seems like you want something like this?

```
$regex = '/Name\:\ ([\w]+)\ ([\w]+)/';
```

Update: try this:

```
$regex = '/Name\:\ [\w\s]+?\]\ [\d]{1}/';
```

For me this matches

```
Name: Foo Bar] 2
```

..but not these:

```
Name: Foo Bar] foo
Name: Foo Baz 5
```

I'm also using short-hand expressions for character classes:

- [\w] is short for [a-zA-Z0-9] ( eg all alphanumeric characters )
- [\s] matches any whitespace
- [\d] matches any number

For safety I'm also using the '?' to match in a non-greedy way, to make sure thw [\w\s]+ match doesn't consume too much of the string.

Answer (score 0):

i think this might be because of the space in the regex also u want to escape the second ]. try

```
$regex = '/Name:\s[a-zA-Z ]*\]\s[0-9]/';
```

Or use a modifier

```
$regex = '/Name: [a-zA-Z ]*\] [0-9]/x';
```

more on modifiers here
[PHP: Possible modifiers in regex patterns - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked. Also, like I said in the original post, the script returns true if I remove the [0-9] part, so while it makes sense to escape that second bracket, I don't think that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works nicely for me with the two examples you gave.

```
$arr = array('Name: Chris] 5', 'Name: Chris] [lorem ipsum]');
foreach ($arr as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/Name: [a-zA-Z ]*] [0-9]/', $str)) {
        echo "$str : OK\n";
    } else {
        echo "$str : KO\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name: Chris] 5 : OK
Name: Chris] [lorem ipsum] : KO
```

May be there are more than one space between `]` and the digit, so your regex should be:

```
[a-zA-Z ]*]\s+[0-9]/
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the issue by attempting different regexes that did basically the same thing. This is what ended up working:

```
$regex = '/Name: [\w ]*][^[]{2}/';
```

Evidently the brackets weren't the problem, but there was something in my original code that wasn't working properly. Thank you everyone for all the help.